# Android native keyboard showing up in Marshmallow Edge devices

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have an Android application. I have a custom keyboard that I am using which is only supposed to show number keyboard. It works fine on all sets of OS with any device. Specifically for Android Marshmallow with Samsung Edge S7 and S6 devices, the native Android keyboard shows up along with the custom keyboard.

How can I disable the native Android keyboard on this combination of devices?

Comment: try adding "android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" in your manifest for all activities

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34019946/how-to-hide-default-android-keyboard-when-custom-keyboard-is-visible

Refer accepted answer if helpful .

Comment: @Nilabja does not work sorry

Comment: @RakshitSoni :: sorry does not work.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and for the newest API I used such a workaround:

```
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
        {
            mTextView.setShowSoftInputOnFocus(false);
        }
```

It works for me.